# Evitar SQL Injection Formulário de Login

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, validação, sql-injection

Bom dia pessoal,

Sou novo no que diz respeito a segurança anti sql injection.
Sempre aprendi apenas a validar os inputs e de seguida usa-los na query, sempre com mysqli_query e mysqli_fetch_array.

Tenho o seguinte código para checkar se o login é correto ou não (funciona sem problema), conseguem dizer se isto evita sql injection? Se não, que medidas devo tomar?
Obrigado pelo vosso tempo e ajuda

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$base_url = strtok($link, '?');              // Get the base url
$parsed_url = parse_url($link);              // Parse it 
$query = $parsed_url['query']; 

if(!isset($query)){
$redireciona=$link;
}else{
$redireciona=substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "failed") - 1);
}

$user = trim($_POST['sp_uname']);
$pass = trim($_POST["sp_pass"]);
$stmt = $ligadb->prepare("SELECT id_user, u_user, u_nome, u_password, u_perfil FROM users WHERE u_user=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user, $nome, $password, $perfil);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
    {
        if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

        {
            if(password_verify($_POST["sp_pass"], $password)){
             $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
             $_SESSION['perfil'] =  $perfil;
             $_SESSION['id'] =  $user_id;
             $_SESSION['nome'] =  $nome;    
            }else{
                 if(!isset($query) || $query==="failed"){
# Redirect user to error page
header('Location: ' . $redireciona . '?failed');

}else{

if (strpos($link, 'failed') !== false) {
 header('Location: ' . $link);
 }else{
        header('Location: ' . $link . '&failed');
 }
    }
            }

           }
      header('Location: ' . $redireciona);

}
else {
    if (strpos($link, 'failed') !== false) {
 header('Location: ' . $link);
 }else{
        header('Location: ' . $link . '&failed');
 }
}
     $stmt->close();
}
else 
{   

}
$ligadb->close();
```

Comment: Isto pode ajudar, é uma excelente resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, uma vez que já utilizo prepared statements no excerto acima queria saber se é suficiente. O problema é que já pesquisei e li tanta coisa que fico confuso com os múltiplos caminhos/soluções, queria saber se este é o caminho certo e se há algo a acrescentar para o melhorar